# Why is my note stacking location so offset after adding more than five?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel in my winforms which stores my UserControl: notes. I offset the value: nextNoteLocation y value by 10 + the height of my note every time a note is added, so each note added will be placed bottom of the previous. The issue comes after placing the 6th note, which is placed in a much higher spacing than the others. I'm not sure where I am causing this to happen.

```
public Point nextNoteLocation = new Point(0, 10);
public Note note;
private void addNoteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        note = new Note();
        currentNote = note;
        note.Location = nextNoteLocation;
        this.notesPanel.Controls.Add(note);
        nextNoteLocation.Y += note.Height + 10;

        MessageBox.Show(nextNoteLocation.ToString());
    }
```

> height of one note is 109. after adding one note, nextNoteLocation.Y =
> 129 after adding two notes, nextNoteLocation.Y = 248 after adding one
> notes, nextNoteLocation.Y = 367 after adding one notes,
> nextNoteLocation.Y = 486 after adding one notes, nextNoteLocation.Y =
> 605 after adding one notes, nextNoteLocation.Y = 724, but it has a
> huge gap between the previous ones. I was wondering if it could be due
> to being below the panel field (where you have to scroll down now).

Comment: Why don't you use a FlowLayoutPanel as container for your UCs, so you don't need to worry about their layout?

Comment: what is the advantage of those? is there a functionality that makes it easier for me?